# Unknown error with System.data.dataset

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, database-connection

I am new to database and SQL, so i have no idea what to initialize at dat_set

My code:

```
public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
{
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
}

private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
    con.Open();
    da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
    da_1.Fill(dat_set);   
    con.Close();
    return dat_set;
}
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: when i run the app this messages pops up: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized

Comment: Identify the method in which you have used `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: You don't even have `SqlCommand`. Here steps: 1)Define your `SqlCommand`. 2)Create `SqlDataReader` with `ExecuteReader`. 3) Fill your `DataTable` with this `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: I have not used any ExecuteReader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize your [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) before calling Fill method.

```
 DataSet dat_set = new DataSet();
```

Example: Not tested code

```
private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
{

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            //Create a SqlDataAdapter 
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            // Open the connection.
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_string, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // Set the SqlDataAdapter's SelectCommand.
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            // Fill the DataSet.
            System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            // Close the connection.
            connection.Close();

            return dataSet;
       }

     return default(System.Data.DataSet);
}
```

Comment: and do i need to provide any info as parameters to the DataSet constructor?

Comment: no, you don need to. I have added the link to MSDN page for more details.

Comment: Agree with @Ehsan. In the parameter of constructor you can specify DataSet Name which is optional.

Comment: Please. consider that using global variables in that way is not a good practice. A refactoring using only local variables is possible